# Accessing derby database from jar

Tags: java, derby, javadb

I have created database in derby and store it in /data folder in the root of my project folder. in the application i am using embedded drivers. when i run my application from netbeans i am getting no errors. when i build the application and run the jar i am getting **database not found error** . Here is the code that i am using to connect to the database.

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");

            Properties p = new Properties();
            p.put("user", "usman");
            p.put("password", "******");
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:data/SalePurchase", p);
```

Can anyone tell me how can i access the database folder "SalePurchase" when i run it in the jar . .

Comment: For good order: is the databse _inside_ the jar, or external? Internal, as resource, you'd better copy it to `System.getProperty("user.home") + "/SalePurchase.db"` or so.

Comment: @JoopEggen i have database folder inside data folder in the root of my project folder. i want to build the project , make the runnable jar of project and access the database

Comment: Then do `File.copy(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/data/SalePurchase.db"), Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/SalePurchase.db"));` to install the database externally; with connection URL "jdbc:derby:~/SalePurchase".

Answer (score 0):

data/SalePurchase is a *relative* path. The question is what is it relative to. The [manual](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/devguide/cdevdvlp13018.html) () states that

> You define the system directory when Derby starts up by specifying a Java system property called derby.system.home.If you do not specify the system directory when starting up Derby, the current directory becomes the system directory.
>
> Derby uses the derby.system.home property to determine which directory is its system directory - and thus what databases are in its system, where to create new databases, and what configuration parameters to use. See the Derby Reference Manual for more information on this property.
>
> If you specify a system directory at startup that does not exist, Derby creates this new directory - and thus a new system with no databases-automatically.